# Minecraft pi not launching

Tags: minecraft, pi

(solved, make sure your graphics driver is correct, dont remember which, its from between fake and legacy. Otherwise, reinstall your os, it should fix then)

Also, thanks to: Anston Sorensen, for trying to help

Question:

When I launch Minecraft pi it shows a black window for a second and closes.

in command line it gives me the error:

failed to add service - already in use?

after command:

sudo minecraft-pi

Comment: You are allowed to answer to your own question, rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge minecraft-pi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-pi
```

If all else fails why not just play the full version of Minecraft? (Minecraft Java Edition). https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=279135